# Spring security: bad credentials - не работает форма входа

Tags: spring, java-ee, spring-security

Здравствуйте, при создании собственной формы входа возникла проблема: при попытке залогиниться появляется ошибка с сообщением bad credentials (хотя если логиниться через форму  - все проходит)

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>    

<security:http pattern="/admin/**" use-expressions="true" name="securityFilterChain" create-session="stateless">
          <security:http-basic/>
          <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />

   </security:http>

   <security:http use-expressions="true">
          <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll()"/>
          <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
          <security:form-login login-page="/login"
                  default-target-url="/restaurants"
                  authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
                  login-processing-url="/spring_security_check"/>
          <security:logout logout-success-url="/login"/>
   </security:http>

   <security:authentication-manager>
          <security:authentication-provider>
                 <security:user-service>
                        <security:user name="anatoly@mail.ru" password="pastol" authorities="ADMIN"/>
                 </security:user-service>
                 <!--<security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                                             users-by-username-query="SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email = ?"
                                             authorities-by-username-query="SELECT u.email, r.role FROM users u, roles r WHERE u.id=r.userid AND u.email = ?"/>-->
                 </security:authentication-provider>
   </security:authentication-manager>
```

---

Форма входа

```
  <form:form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" action="spring_security_check" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name='username'>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name='password'>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Войти</button>
  </form:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не указали имена полей в форме ввода.

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login"
              default-target-url="/restaurants"
              authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
              username-parameter="username"
              password-parameter="password" />
```

Во-вторых, зачем `login-processing-url`? При задании этого параметра необходим метод с этим урлом, который будет этот запрос обрабатывать. Зачем? Можно же воспользоваться стандартным. Собственно, ошибка именно потому, что нет этого урла.

```
<c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
<form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
```

В-третьих, если у вас Spring Security 4, обратите внимание на [этот мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/524065/210568).

Удачи!